# How to simplify a case when *condition* in (select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that create the relationship between users and groups that looks like:

UserGroups

| group_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |

and the table `users` looks like:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Mary |
| 3 | Bob |
| 4 | Carol |

And I'm **successfully** selecting my results like this:

```
SELECT
...,
CASE
    WHEN users.id in (SELECT user_id from usergoups where group_id = 1) and not in (SELECT user_id from usergoups where group_id = 2) then 1
    WHEN users.id in (SELECT user_id from usergoups where group_id = 2) and not in (SELECT user_id from usergoups where group_id = 1) then 2
    WHEN users.id in (SELECT user_id from usergoups where group_id = 1) and in (SELECT user_id from usergoups where group_id = 2) then 1
    else class.group
end as class_group
...
LEFT JOIN users on users.id = 1
```

for the following sample output:

| class_id | class_group |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |

I was wondering if it is possible to simplify the select and make it more efficient reducing the number of selections, as i could just have something like:

```
...
LEFT JOIN usergroups on usergroups.user_id = users.id
...
```

The only line that i could think of was:

```
...
WHEN 2 in usergroups then...
```

but it just trows a sintax error as i kinda expected

Comment: Can you share sample input tables?

Comment: This seems like it can be done with windows functions. Could you please share both, your MySQL version and what exactly is your query supposed to do? For example, if there is a `group_id` 3 and `user` 1 has relation to it, the query should output `user` 1 with `group_id` 1 still?

Comment: I think you're missing the "*users*" table. Also if you can provide a sample of the output table by updating your post, it would be easier for people to understand the overall post. Not the full output, just a sample of it, with respect to the already provided sample input.

Comment: @lemon think you want output tables instead input, right? it is such a big select, but for these means the case needs to output a defined integer, a user can be in group 1, group 2 or both

Comment: @JettoMartínez editted to fit what you asked, group 3 should not have a impact on the output, showing the original value of the line instead a forced integer. Version is 5.6.51.

Comment: *And I'm successfully selecting my results like this* This query seems to be excessively complex. Also you use `class.group` which is not described.

Comment: You may combine options 1 and 3 of your CASE to single `WHEN users.id in (SELECT user_id from usergoups where group_id = 1) then 1`. Moreover, you can rewrite this to correlated EXISTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could avoid correlated subqueries in expressions in the SELECT list, if we  instead use an inline view (mysql calls it a *derived table*) to check for the existence of rows in `user_groups`.  Following this line in the outer query

```
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = 1
```

I'd add an outer join to an inline view query something like this:

```
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ug.user_id
                     , MAX(CASE ug.group_id WHEN 1 THEN ug.group_id ELSE NULL END) AS g1
                     , MAX(CASE ug.group_id WHEN 2 THEN ug.group_id ELSE NULL END) AS g2
                  FROM user_groups ug
                 WHERE ug.group_id IN (1,2)
                 GROUP
                    BY ug.user_id
              ) g
           ON g.user_id = users.id
```

The view query will return one (or zero) rows for each `user_id` in the `user_groups` table, so it flattens to

```
         user_id    g1    g2
         -------  ----  ----
               1     1     2
               2  NULL     2
               3     1  NULL
```

For improved performance, if the outer query is restricting results to just one user, e.g.

```
    ON users.id = 1
```

We can include a matching restriction in the inline view query,

```
                 WHERE ug.group_id IN (1,2)
                   AND ug.user_id = 1         /* <-- add this to match the condition in the outer query */
```

---

In the SELECT list of the outer query, we can do the conditional checks,

```
          CASE
          WHEN g.g1 AND g.g2 IS NULL THEN 1
          WHEN g.g2 AND g.g1 IS NULL THEN 2
          WHEN g.g1                  THEN 1
          ELSE class.group
          END AS foo
```

Note that the first `WHEN` is redundant. If the first WHEN condition is TRUE, then we know the second WHEN condition cannot be TRUE, so we could check that first, and then the third WHEN condition covers the first. This would return an equivalent result,

```
          CASE
          WHEN g.g2 AND g.g1 IS NULL THEN 2
          WHEN g.g1                  THEN 1
          ELSE class.group
          END
```

---

If we weren't needing to return `class.group` from the CASE expression, I'd be more tempted to move the logic down into the inline view. (We could move the checks for group_id 2 and group_id 1, and return 2 or 1 or NULL to the outer query, but we'd still need an expression to check the return from g to see if we return that, or return `class.group`

Comment: Even tho I was looking after an aproach using "...LEFT JOIN usergroups on usergroups.user_id = users.id...", this is way more elegant. Also thx to you and @Akina for pointing the logical redundancy.

Comment: added another answer, with two outer joins to `user_groups` but for that approach, we need guaranteed uniqueness of (user_id,group_id) i.e. no duplicate rows in user_groups. (there arent any duplicates shown in the original question, BUT that doesnt mean there wont be at some point; we cant rely on uniqueness if its not enforced by a database constraint;  the approach in this answer doesnt require guaranteed uniqueness

Comment: I have a script running that takes care not to insert duplicates, so i dont think that should be an issue

Answer (score 0):

Another way to avoid correlated subqueries in the SELECT list, the syntax is a bit cleaner than the approach in my other answer,

BUT we would only do this...

IF (and only IF) we have some *guarantee* that rows in `user_groups` are UNIQUE i.e. if theres a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE KEY` constraint on the `(group_id,user_id)` tuple (or it could be the other way around `(user_id,group_id)`)

THEN we could use two outer joins to the `user_groups` table

So following this line:

```
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = 1
```

We could add

```
    LEFT JOIN user_groups g1 ON g1.group_id = 1 AND g1.user_id = users.id
    LEFT JOIN user_groups g2 ON g2.group_id = 2 AND g2.user_id = users.id
```

Then in our expression in the SELECT list could be

```
    CASE
    WHEN g2.group_id AND g1.group_id IS NULL THEN 2
    WHEN g1.group_id THEN 1
    ELSE class.group
    END AS class_group
```

NOTE: in MySQL, when a numeric is evaluated as a boolean, a value of 0 (zero) is FALSE, any non-zero value is TRUE, and NULL is NULL.

So the above is equivalent shorthand for

```
    CASE
    WHEN g2.group_id <> 0 AND g1.group_id IS NULL THEN 2
    WHEN g1.group_id <> 0 THEN 1
    ELSE class.group
    END AS class_group
```

---

N.B. without guaranteed uniqueness, the JOINs have potential to match multiple rows from `user_groups` (e.g. consider if there are two rows `(1,1),(1,1)` ), that would double the number of rows returned, which we probably do not want)

The approach in my other answer is not subject to the same uniqueness requirement; any duplicate rows for a `(user_id,group_id)` will be collapsed into a single row for the `user_id` by the `GROUP BY` in the inline view.